# Why I get 0 when I check a simple IF condition in two excel tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables, table A, table B and I do the following in cell of table A

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(tableB[@[Field]]);TRUE;FALSE)
```

but I get always 0.

I have the two tables in the same worksheet

What I am missing here???

Comment: Would it be possible to upload a dummy spreadsheet where you can put this occurrence in so we can have a look? (you could use dropbox/google drive/mega.nz to upload it and share the link here)

Answer (score -1):

What version of Excel are you using?
Edit: depending on your regional settings the following may not apply - You are using semicolons in your formula which won't work as they should be commas.

should be more like

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(TableB[Field]),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Please note your formula could be simplified further by just using

```
=ISNUMBER(TableB[Field])
```

Also check the cell formatting of the cell in which the formula is and list that so we can see if this is affecting

Comment: The OP's syntax is perfectly valid for the table field syntax. Semicolons are used instead of commas and vice versa depending on the regional settings

Comment: @Jerry so how to debug this kind of situation?

Comment: @Nikos What version of Excel are you using? I'm using 365, and am unable to reproduce your problem

Comment: It is Excel 2010

Comment: @Nikos [I can't actually reproduce the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akvzA.png) I'm trying to think of what might be causing the problem, but still working on it

Comment: @Nikos I just tried in Excel 2010 and can't reproduce the problem there either...